# QlikView .Trabajando con Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo el siguiente trozo de código en `Qlik` `view`:

```
"Remove(Row, RowCnd(Interval, Pos(Top, 2), Pos(Bottom, 1), Select(1, 0)))"
```

Alguien me podría explicar mas o menos lo que esta haciendo por favor, Se podría convertir en formato `SQL`?

Perdonar os adjunto la tabla completa de `QlikView`:

```
Aux1:
LOAD @5
FROM
[$(vGBUSharedrive)Stratus_2\StratusExtractionReport_NEW_WEEK2.xlsx]
(ooxml, explicit labels, table is Worksheet, filters(
Remove(Row, RowCnd(Interval, Pos(Top, 2), Pos(Bottom, 1), Select(1, 0)))
));

LET vPeriodOfDate = if(MID(PEEK('@5',0,'Aux1'),10,2)=MID(PEEK('@5',0,'Aux1'),25,2),MID(PEEK('@5',0,'Aux1'),10,2),'Differents Months');
LET vYearOfDate = if(MID(PEEK('@5',0,'Aux1'),13,4)=MID(PEEK('@5',0,'Aux1'),28,4),MID(PEEK('@5',0,'Aux1'),15,2),'Differents Years');
```

Comment: Cuando me refiero a formato SQL, quiero decir si tengo una DataBase, podría hacer algo parecido? En plan : un Select* from (x tabla ). Where aplicar la condición  mencionada

Answer (score -1):

básicamente son las condiciones como se va a abrir dicho archivo, como quitar una columna y agregar otra con un ID consecutivo y otras cosas mas.
si fuera el caso de que agregaras mas archivos como ese y los concatenas, todos los demás archivos se abrirían con las mismas condiciones.

En SQL me parece que es lo que hace un Store Procedure.

Comment: Te invito a que leas: [answer] y [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/107347)